# Use jQuery to "change" HTML?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to change the order that a set of img tags show up on my page. Using insertAfter() or after() works fine, and it moves the img *on the page*, but it doesn't change them in the actual HTML. So when I move the first img to the bottom of the stack, eq(0) *(which should select the img on top)* still selects the one that just got "moved" to the bottom instead of the new first img. Is there a way to actually change the HTML position of the imgs so that I can re-use the same jQuery code on them?

**Edit:**

HTML

```
<div id='slideshow'>
    <img class='slide' />
    <img class='slide' />
    <img class='slide' />
    <img class='slide' />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var slide = $('.slide');
slide.eq(0).insertAfter(slide.eq(slide.length - 1));
```

The second line puts the first img behind the last img. But then, the next time it try and use the **slide.eq(0)** to target the first img, it targets the one that I moved to the bottom instead of the one that *should* be on the top.

Comment: Please provide the HMTL and JavaScript code you are using. Preferably you would come up with the smallest possible example that illustrates your problem. Just telling us what is happening is not very useful without the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to lack of code, here's a shot in the dark:

You are selecting the images, say with `$("img")`. This gives you an object like so:

- `[0]` First image
- `[1]` Second image
- `[2]` Third image

You then move the first image to be at the end. Your result is:

- `[1]` Second image
- `[2]` Third image
- `[0]` First image

Notice how the indexes continue to refer to the same images as before! Just because you've changed the order of the elements, doesn't mean they've updated in the jQuery object too - that would be WAY to intensive to keep track of.

So now you acess `.eq(0)`. The first image. Doesn't matter that it's the third image on the page now, it's still the first image in the jQuery object.

You will need to rebuild your `$("img")` object to get the updated indexes.

Comment: Alright, the explanation make sense, thanks :) How would you suggest updating the index? Can I restate the variables? I have added the code now. I first declared all the img with the code with *var slide = $('.slide');* should I, after moving the imgs, say *slide = $('slide');* to update the indexes?

Answer (score 1):

Using `insertAfter` or `after` **will** move the element in the DOM.

Your problem is that the jQuery object (unlike, for instance, `getElementsByClassName`) doesn't maintain a live HTML collection, it just has an array of the elements that matched whatever it used when it was constructed.

You'll need to either create a new jQuery object, or keep track of which elements in the array you have dealt with already, or use something other than jQuery which does maintain a live HTML collection.

Comment: Too slow :p but good to know that you had the same thoughts as me on this.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery collections are not live, so they are not updated when the DOM changes.

I suggest using native vanilla-js live collections, which will get updated.

Compare the following:

```js
var $el = $(document.body),
    $children = $el.children(), // It's NOT a live collection
    $first = $children.eq(0);
$el.append($first);
// `$children` has NOT been updated
$children[0] == $first[0]; // `true`
```

```js
var el = document.body,
    children = el.children, // It's a live collection
    first = children[0];
el.appendChild(first);
// `children` has been updated
children[0] == first; // `false`
```